# PieCloudDB Database's Indexes

Tags: indexing

In the PieCloudDB documentation, I could not find a reference to using Indexes.

Does PieCloudDB Database support Indexes? If not, what is the alternative approach to performance optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PieCloudDB Database support brand new Data Skipping index. Zone Map index and BRIN (Block Range Index) index are specific implementations of Data Skipping techniques commonly used in OLAP scenarios.

Its performance boosts come through by minimizing unnecessary scans. PieCloudDB employs data skipping technology, which skips scanning data blocks or partitions that do not meet the query criteria by precomputing statistical information. This effectively reduces I/O operations, thereby accelerating the execution speed of queries.